# STArray indexing gives a type error

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to solve this year's [Advent of Code](http://adventofcode.com/2017/) using Haskell, and ran into an issue on day 5 which asks us to jump around instructions in a list of jumps and count how many steps it takes until you exit the instruction set. I implemented this correctly with `IArray`s, but it seems like a waste to re-initialize this huge array over and over so I'm trying to re-implement with `MArray` instead, which is throwing me into the scary world of the `ST` monad.

Here is my correctly working code:

```
import qualified Data.Array as A

-- sample input
day5Input :: [Int]
day5Input = [0, -1, 1032] ++ replicate 1030 [1]  -- to fill the array

day5Array :: A.Array Int Int
day5Array = A.listArray (0, 1032) day5Input

p1Day5Result :: Integer
p1Day5Result = go 0 0 day5Array where
  go :: Integer -> Int -> A.Array Int Int -> Integer
  go c i a | i > ubound || i < lbound = c
           | otherwise                = let n = a A.! i
                                            i' = i+n
                                            n' = n+1
                                            a' = a A.// [(i, n')]
                                        in  go (c+1) i' a'
  (lbound, ubound) = A.bounds day5Array
```

which I attempted to re-create using an `STArray` with:

```
import Data.Array.MArray as MA
import Data.Array.ST (STArray, runSTArray)
import Control.Monad.ST

-- sample input
day5Input :: [Int]
day5Input = [0, -1, 1032] ++ replicate 1030 [1]  -- to fill the array

testMArray :: ST s (STArray s Int Int)
testMArray = MA.newListArray (0, 1032) day5Input

mStep :: ST s Integer
mStep = go 0 0 testMArray where
  go :: Integer -> Int -> ST s (STArray s Int Int) -> ST s Integer
  go c i arr | i > ubound || i < lbound = return c
             | otherwise                = do
                     n <- MA.readArray arr i
                     let i' = i+n
                         n' = n+1
                     MA.writeArray arr i n'
                     go (c+1) i' arr
  (lbound, ubound) = (0, 1032)  -- sub-question, how do I query for this
                                -- like I did with A.bounds above?
```

However I get the error:

```
day5.hs:1091:44: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `s1' with actual type `Int'
      `s1' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          go :: forall s1.
                Integer -> Int -> ST s1 (STArray s1 Int Int) -> ST s1 Integer
```

I'm not seeing how my code differs from [this example code](https://wiki.haskell.org/Modern_array_libraries#Mutable_arrays_in_ST_monad_.28module_Data.Array.ST.29) that works. Please advise.

Comment: What is `testMArray`? I bet you need `testMArray >>= go 0 0` or similar.

Comment: @DanielWagner `testMArray :: ST s (STArray s Int Int)`. I'll edit.

Comment: @AdamSmith In case you're interested, I did the same but using mutable vectors: https://github.com/ZedPea/advent-of-code/blob/master/day05-2.hs

Comment: @Zpalmtree Thanks! Can you quickly summarize the difference between Arrays and Vectors?

Comment: @Zpalmtree also: share and [share alike](https://gitlab.com/nottheeconomist/adventofcode_hs/)

Comment: @AdamSmith I'm not really sure what the difference is to be honest. I believe they both have O(1) access times, but after looking at the array API, vector looked a lot more easy to use, it has a lot more of the functions that you're used to from lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply seem to be mixing up `ST` actions which produce arrays with the arrays themselves. The fix is pretty easy: run such actions to get their arrays. Here's the minimal fix I needed to make to get this to compile (no idea if it is "correct" -- just that it type-checks).

1. Run the `ST` action.

   ```
   mStep = testMArray >>= go 0 0 where
   ```
2. Give `go` a type that expects an array, not an `ST` action.

   ```
   go :: Integer -> Int -> STArray s Int Int -> ST s Integer
   ```
3. Define `day5Input`. (Presumably you need not backport this fix.)

   ```
   day5Input = undefined
   ```

For your subquestion, you can use

```
getBounds :: (Ix i, MArray a e m) => a i e -> m (i, i)
```

to get the bounds dynamically. So:

```
mStep = do
    arr <- testMArray
    (lbound, ubound) <- MA.getBounds arr
    go lbound ubound 0 0 arr
    where
    go :: Int -> Int -> Integer -> Int -> STArray s Int Int -> ST s Integer
    go lbound ubound c i arr | -- same as before
        -- until the very last line
        go lbound ubound (c+1) i' arr
```

Comment: Yes I think that's likely. So `testMArray` is not itself a stateful array, just an action that produces one, yes? One of these days I'm going to understand Haskell, and my Godhood shall be magnificent ;)

Comment: @AdamSmith Correct!

Comment: Reading this I can't stop wondering why `MA.getBounds` returns the pair inside the monad, instead of outside it. Does `MArray` have some instances of array types supporting resizing, to justify this monad nature of `MA.getBounds`? Possibly, it's slightly more general than needed in practice (?).

Comment: @chi I believe you've nailed it: `MArray` was designed to be flexible enough to handle resizable arrays, but no extant instances take advantage of this.